# Getting Top-K Input vectors through Attention Mechanism in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm currently working with TensorFlow and trying to get the 10 highest features for a classification problem. Here's my current code snippet:

```
    attention_map = attention_model(features)
    top_logits, top_indices = tf.math.top_k(attention_map, k=10)
    top_vectors = tf.gather_nd(features, top_indices)

    output = tf.gather_nd(features, top_vectors)
    return output
```

Features is a dataset of size `(100, 30)`. Since we're taking the top 10 vectors, I'm expecting `output` should have a dimensionality of `(100, 10)`, however, I'm getting a Tensor of size much smaller, which doesn't make much sense.